# How to detect transaction is running in Percona?

Tags: mysql, database, percona

For example this is working for MariaDB and all three queries return 1:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT @@in_transaction;

SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.session_variables WHERE variable_name = 'in_transaction';

SELECT session_value FROM information_schema.system_variables WHERE variable_name = 'in_transaction';
```

And all these queries are not working for Percona 8.0.22-13.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 supports this (I haven't checked 5.6 because it's past end-of-life already), and therefore Percona should too, because Percona is a branch (not a fork) of MySQL.

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_trx 
       where trx_mysql_thread_id = connection_id()\G
```

If it returns no result, then the thread has not started a transaction.

Note that you can use `start transaction` and yet the query returns no result. A transaction does not really start until you execute the first statement against a transactional table.